# CouchDB administrator password reset

Tags: permissions, database-administration, couchdb

I have an install of couchDB, and somewhere along the line, a malformed request via CURL has my admin accound with a password that I don't know. Short of setting up another Couch server, then replicating to it and vice versa after a reinstall, is there anything I can do?  I have edited local.ini, I deleted it.  I replaced it with the one from the source folder.  I restart not only couch but the entire server after every change because nothing seems to work.  Anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 0):

Ignore this question.  For some reason, on the eight-thousandth iteration of doing the same thing, it randomly worked.

Comment: I take that back.  When couch runs as a service, it's not loading the local.ini file, only when I launch it from the shell.